# How to listen to FragmentStatePagerAdapter setPrimaryItem from a Activity

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I just started coding android and I have a ViewPager inside a fragment and what I want to do is how to listen to setPrimaryItem event of ViewPagerAdapter from it's activity so I can pass data from the adapter to the activity.

I tried using interface but I don't know how to get the activity inside the adapter.

Comment: *I tried using interface but it does not work inside an adapter for some reason*. Can you post the code?

Comment: What I mean is it does not work because I cannot get the activity from there or just I dont know how to property implement a interface inside a adapter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is basic observer pattern, you'll encounter it a lot. I did it like this for `FragmentPagerAdapter`, `FragmentStatePagerAdapter` should work the same.

```
public abstract class ObservableFragmentPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

    private Fragment mCurrentFragment = null;
    private OnPrimaryItemChangedListener mPrimaryItemListener = null;

    public ObservableFragmentPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
    }

    @Override
    public void setPrimaryItem(ViewGroup container, int position, Object object) {
        super.setPrimaryItem(container, position, object);

        if (mCurrentFragment != object) {
            Fragment newFragment = (Fragment) object;
            if (mPrimaryItemListener != null) {
                mPrimaryItemListener.onPrimaryItemChanged(mCurrentFragment, newFragment);
            }
            mCurrentFragment = newFragment;
        }
    }

    public void setOnPrimaryItemChangedListener(OnPrimaryItemChangedListener listener) {
        mPrimaryItemListener = listener;
    }

    public interface OnPrimaryItemChangedListener {
        void onPrimaryItemChanged(Fragment oldFragment, Fragment newFragment);
    }
}
```

Subscribing works the same way as e.g. setting an `OnClickListener`.

Comment: Thank you, you saved my day wondering how to do it using interface. Great answer!

Comment: If you wish to know about it within the fragment itself, you get a call to setUserVisibleHint automatically.